# Specific Approximate Matching in Python

Tags: python, string, fuzzywuzzy

**PROBLEM**

I want to implement a type of specific approximate matching of two sentences in Python.

Example -

```
s_1 = "I hope you are safe from COVID-19 today"
s_2 = "I hope you're safe from COVID 19 today"

score = get_similarity(s_1, s_2)
```

*OR*

```
s_1 = "I allow account access to facebook"
s_2 = "I allow an account access to face book"

score = get_similarity(s_1, s_2)
```

**APPROACH**

I tried using `FuzzyWuzzy` to get a partial ratio of matching, but I have observed that with that, even if `s_2` is `"I allow an account access to`, without the `face book`, it will give a high similarity score.

**ASK**

Is there a better way so that I can take into account a similarity of the entire sentence into consideration?

NOTE - `s_2` might or might not be a transcription from a from a video file so will have to account for that delta in getting a precise text. Example, `FACEBOOK can be transcribed as FACE BOOK`

Comment: in fuzzywuzzy there is fuzz.ratio which will calculate a distance based on the whole sentence. Probably it makes sence to do some preprocessing like e.g. to lowercase both strings.

Comment: Even after preprocessing, `fuzzywuzzy` marks `s_1` and `s_2` as similar